# Django QuerySet.extra() and PostgreSQL age() function

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm trying to write a filter in Django where I first filter the queryset and then I'd like to again filter it with the following SQL-statemnet:

```
SELECT * FROM user, 
    (select EXTRACT(year FROM age(birthday)) as age FROM user) as age 
WHERE age.age between 20 AND 40;
```

How can I do that?

Edit: The model is the following

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you know you can [chain filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters)?

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().year
u = User.objects.filter(x=42).filter(birthday__year__range=(now-40,now-20))
```

Comment: Of course I know about chaining, but I actually want to do the calculation on the db because of performance. Apart from that with your approach I get the following error:
    
    FieldError: Join on field 'birthday' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?

Comment: It is a DateField(), so it should work? I already use it with the whole date, but only the year doesn't work.